# Will MonoDroid give me a apk which can be sent by email?

Tags: xamarin.android, apk

I am a software developer in the C# world.
I have developed a app using Java and Eclips (to look a little beyond the fence).
Now I am planing to use Monodroid to develop my apps.

On of the major questions to me is : Will monodroid give me a apk which I can forward to friends without going through the web store?

Regards
Rainer

Comment: You should ask Mondroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you purchase a license for Mono for Android you will be able to do this. The evaluation version only allows for deployment to the emulator, so the license is needed for deployment to a device.

An APK is always generated by the packaging step of a Mono for Android build. Debug builds make use of a shared runtime to keep the package size down and make for faster development/deployment. When you compile in release mode, the Mono runtime will also be packaged within the APK, making it a standalone application. You can take this APK and distribute it however you like, whether it be through Google Play or privately.

Xamarin has some good documentation [available here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/build_process) on the build process, as well as documentation on [packaging your app for release](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Preparing_Package_for_Android_Marketplace). Even though you don't want to deploy to the market, all the steps there except the last one still apply.

Answer (score 1):

Hello when compiling in release mode you have to run the release version on your device or the emulator and when visual studio is finished making the app you will find in the release folder (same folder structure as c# applications) a file called *-Signed.apk that can email. you have to be in release mode and reach the final steps to have Monodroid integrate everything in a standalone apk.